# C timers and threads again

Tags: c, timer, pthreads

Can someone help me to complete my code with a function that can check the result of a timer "check_timer" and another one that reset this timer if it had expired "reset_timer"?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define GLOBAL_TIMER  8 * 60 * 60


typedef struct protocol_type {
 int protocol_number;
 char *protocol_name;
 pthread_t thread_timer_id;
} protocol_type_t;

pthread_mutex_t mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;


/* call back function - inform the user the time has expired */
void timeout_call_back(pthread_t thread_id)
{
    printf("Welcome thread %ld, your time is up ===\n", pthread_self());
    // doing some other stuff
}

/* Go to sleep for a period of seconds */
static void* start_timer(void *args)
{
    /* function pointer */
    void (*finish_function)(pthread_t);


    int seconds = *((int*) args);

    finish_function = timeout_call_back;

 struct timeval now;
 struct timespec timeout;

 pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
 printf("thread ID : %ld, are waiting for %d seconds to to expire\n", pthread_self(), seconds);
 gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
 timeout.tv_sec = now.tv_sec + seconds;
 timeout.tv_nsec = now.tv_usec * 1000;
 pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond, &mut, &timeout);
 (*finish_function)(pthread_self());
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

// This function is in MT environnement and is running inside a daemon
int received_buffer_parser(char *received_buffer) {
 pthread_mutex_t mut_main = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; 
 protocol_type_t *my_protocol;

 // Identify protocol type
 my_protocol = protocol_identifier(received_buffer);

 // Check if i received it in the last 8 hours in safe 
 pthread_mutex_lock(&mut_main);
    if (check_timer(my_protocol->thread_id) has expired) { // I want to write this function
  // I want to reset thread timer
   launch_new_timer(my_protocol->thread_id)
 }
 else {
  // doing some stuff
  // dump data to the disk
 }
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut_main);

 return 0;
}

int launch_new_timer(pthread_t thread_id)
{
 int rc;
 int seconds = GLOBAL_TIMER;

    rc =  pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, start_timer, (void *) &seconds);
    if(rc)
     printf("Failed to create thread1\n");

    pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

---

#### Clarification

I clarify here the real context of my code:
I receive from the network some types of different protocols packets(ICMP, SSH, RIP, OSPF, BGP...), and i want to:

1. identify every type of packets, let say with : identify_protocol(char *received_buffer), I got this function, it's ok.
2. Check if i receive this type of protocols in the last 8 hours (THE TIMER OF EACH PROTOCOL TYPE EXPIRE AFTER 8 HOURS), two choices:

a. if so, I dump the result data into a specific file on the disk.

b. no, I didn't receive this type in the last 8 HOURS i create a new thread (in my code i simplify, with thread1, thread2 and thread3, this threads are 3 threads used to be a timers for three protocols types) - i start a new timer with : start_timer(void *args) function do this job.

My main question is how to be able to check the result of my timers in a safe manner and then decide i reset the timer or not.

I design the finish_function at the beginning to help me to check when the timer has expired.

Feel free to give me a better design for best performances for my program.

My system is Linux.

Comment: There is no reason to use a condition variable for a timed sleep. Simply use `nanosleep`.

Comment: Thanks, how to use nanosleep in my case, it's a blocking call? and how i can write a check_timer function to check if the timer has expired or not when i receive a new protocol packet?

Comment: Note that `pthread_cond_timedwait()` is a blocking call too.  Especially if there isn't a thread able to signal the condition.

Comment: See also [SO 4705563](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705563/how-to-check-thread-timers-results-in-safe-manner).  It is related, but different.

Comment: so how can i deal with that? maybe the design of my program is not good. IT'S REALLY HARD TO IMPLEMENT an asynchronous timer in c and check from time to time if it has expired? i googled a lot and this problem seems to be very hard!

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, i know it's the the same topic, but i need really to fix this problem for tomorrow and i m at my computer for hours trying to fix this problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check for timers that merely expire, you don't need to use threads and synchronization at all. Simply keep global variables indicating the start time of the timer. So

- when the timer starts, set a global variable (one per protocol) to gettimeofday()
- when you want to check whether the timer has expired for a protocol, see whether gettimeofday()-starttime(protocol) is <8h

If you want to be notified on timer expiry, I recommend to use alarm(2). It only has second resolution, but that should be good enough for 8h timeouts. Whenever a timer is set, cancelled, or reset, compute the minimum timeout of any of the timers, then call alarm with that timeout. In the signal handler, perform the processing that you want to do on reception of timeout. Alternatively, do nothing in the signal handler, and just trust that any pending system call will be interrupted, and check all timers for expiry on EINTR.

**Edit**: alarm works like this

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
void timeout(int ignored)
{
   printf("timed out\n");
}

void main()
{
    signal(SIGALRM, timeout);
    alarm(10);
    pause();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin for the answer, the problem is that i don't know in advance which protocol packet i will receive nor their number (when i receive a new one i just add it to a linked list) so i can't have a global variable per protocol! Some sample working code will be very very helpful :). THANKS AGAIN.

Comment: In addition of this, i need to be informed when a timer expire for a certain protocol, so i can move his data file to another directory.

Comment: If you need timers keyed by protocol, make a linked list of running timers. Keep the list sorted by increasing timeout. Always call alarm() for the smallest timeout value.

Comment: Ok thanks, and how to call alarm to inform me that timer has expired so i stop dumping data to a specific file and create a new one?

Comment: Another thing, is it better to use time_t or struct timeval?

Comment: Any idea about how alarm() can inform me that timer has expired?

Comment: alarm will send SIGALRM when the timeout has been reached, so you need to install a signal handler (using signal). Using time_t is fine.

Comment: Sorry, but i'm a it confused on how to combine alarm and difftime with time_t? I think that i need also to use a while loop with alarm() call to continously check if the SIGALRM is catched, and i'm not sure that while loop is very easy to use in my case.

Comment: You don't need to use difftime - regular int arithmetic will work fine on time_t. You can then call `alarm(timeout-time(NULL))`.

Comment: I don't understand SIGALRM, when my alarm expired then a SIGALRM signal is generated, so how can i catch it without a while loop?

Comment: Ok, but still confused, i think that ther's no chance for me to use other thing than an infinite while loop:                           int gotAlarm;

void catch(int sig) {
 gotAlarm = 1;
}


...

signal(SIGALRM, catch);

...
gotAlarm = 0;

alarm(TIMER);

while (!gotAlarm) {
 // some stuff
}

Comment: Instead of the while loop, you need to perform some blocking system call (such as actually receiving the data that you are processing from the network). If you really have nothing to do, call pause(2).

Comment: Can you tell me PLEASE where to put the alarm function and the SIGALRM catcher in my code? I don't really understand what you mean!!!

Comment: See my edit for an example of how to use alarm. Please run the program to be sure to understand what it does.

Comment: Ok i understand but why using pause?

Comment: If you don't have pause(), then the program will continue after the alarm() call; main will just exit, and the program be done. In your case, instead of calling pause, I recommend to continue waiting for additional packets to arrive.

Comment: Thanks, In my case when the timer expire i need to move the file that contain the data to another directory. How can i deal with that?

Comment: Are you really asking here how to move a file from one folder to another? This is out of scope of the original question.

Comment: Sorry, but the function void timeout(int ignored) doesn't allow me to pass any persistant parameter(a parameter that can tell me which protocol has his timer expired!) that can tell me when my timer expire, so that i can moves my files to another directory(I know how to deal with that).

Comment: If you have a global list of timers that you are waiting for, ordered by increasing timeout, and you always alarm() for the earliest timeout, then, when a timeout occurs, it will be for the first entry of the list. So go to the list of timers, take the first one, and find the filename/protocol number/directory/whatever there.

Comment: HOW CAN I SEE IF THE TIMER HAS EXPIRED???? void timeout(int ignored) return void and print some strings it's really not usefull to tell to my program something like : if (YOU SEE THE STRING "timed out") then tell me isn't?

Comment: Ok, sorry but i think you don't understand really what is my problem! BUT THANKS FOR ALL THIS TIPS :)