# How to add extra delay while opening gdb

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb

This is regarding to add some extra delay while opening gdb.
The scenario is something like this:

1. From c++ I use to call my gdb. which is auto configured with host setup in .gdbinit file. Target release localhost:PortNumber
2. And gdb debugger stops at its reset vector location.
3. I am giving the reset vector address through a pin prior to opening gdb, which should be updated and gdb should stop at new location.
4. but gdb is still stops at its initial reset vector location.
5. So, I need to give a short delay while opening the gdb.

How this can be done?
Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the gdb command `python import time; time.sleep(0.01)` do what you want?

Comment: Thanks mark, its same as sleep in c/c++.

Answer (score 0):

See also this post: [How to use the sleep function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818084/what-is-the-proper-include-for-the-function-sleep-in-c)

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("starting gdb");
    Sleep(5000);
    printf("resume program");
}
```

Specify the delay in **milli**seconds

Comment: Hi @Anteino, thanks for the valuable input is possible without adding sleep or wait()? Like something while opening gdb only ? or in .gdbinit

Comment: Well, tell me exactly what you are trying to do first, please. I thought you wanted to stall the program until gdb was loaded. You can insert the command for starting gdb on the line where I wrote `printf("starting gdb");` The program will then wait 5000 milliseconds and continue.

Comment: I want to give delay not from cpp but while opening GDB, i.e when gdb calls its .gdbinit file, it should open after few ms.

Comment: So you're working from the command line then? Please give us a little more info on what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Okay, let me explain ... i have a cpp from where I open my gdb. While opening gdb it is  automatically configured  (from my .gdbinit file) the local host set-up to debug my source. So, I need a short delay when my gdb opens. I don't want to put sleep or wait in my cpp. I just want, when I call my gdb it should open with some delay.

Comment: I believe this thread answers your question then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708760/c-timers-and-threads-again