# Timered operations in a critical section [C]

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, timer, mutex

I'm coding in C on Ubuntu.

I need to write a thread called for example "timeredThread" that do some operations in a critical section after N microseconds like the following:

```
void * timeredThread(void)
{
    sleep(TIMEOUT);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    //operations
    pthead_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

}
```

Also, I need another thread, called for example "timerManager", that can reset the previous timer. My first idea was to create a "timerManager" that kills "timeredThread" and create another one, but this does not work because if I kill "timeredThread" with pthread_cancel() when it's waiting for the mutex I create a deadlock. Deadlock is created because the mutex is in the lock state.

What can I do about it?
Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: What you are trying to do is a widely used concept. Check out what other people are doing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708760/c-timers-and-threads-again If you google "timer thread in C" you get back lots of results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
pthread_mutex_t watchdog_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  watchdog_cond  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
int reset_watchdog = 0;

void reset_watchdog(void) {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&watchdog_mutex);
   reset_watchdog = 1;
   pthread_cond_signal(&watchdog_cond);
   pthead_mutex_unlock(&watchdog_mutex);
}

void watchdog(void) {
   struct timespec sleep_until = { 0 };
   sleep_until.tv_sec = time(NULL) + TIMEOUT;

   pthread_mutex_lock(&watchdog_mutex);

   // Loop until a time out.
   while (!pthread_cond_timedwait(&watchdog_cond, &watchdog_mutex, &sleep_until)) {
      if (reset_watchdog) {
         sleep_until.tv_sec = time() + TIMEOUT;
         reset_watchdog = 0;
      }
   }

   pthead_mutex_unlock(&watchdog_mutex);

   // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, if i want a timer in microseconds what can I do? With this solution I can only set a timer in seconds

Comment: @ABC, Actually, this solution supports nanoseconds. I set `sleep_until.tv_nsec` to zero, but you can set it to any amount you want.

Comment: First thanks for the answer. When I set sleep_until.tv_nsec to a number different than 0 pthread_cond_timedwait return immediately. Why?


I set in this way:
sleep_until.tv_nsec = time(NULL) + TIME;

for example

Comment: I have this: sleep_until.tv_sec = time(NULL) + TIMEOUT;
            sleep_until.tv_nsec = time(NULL) + 1;

So I have added only one line to your old code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219430/discussion-between-abc-and-ikegami).